# Tumblr: Remove Read More link

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

Is there any way to remove the `Read More` link tumblr adds in Posts bodies? 
consider this page www.lowcoupling.com
since the post titles are already links to the post body I don't need the `Read More` link is there any way not to have it?

Comment: you can add `a.read_more { display: none; }` to your css

Comment: ahah so nice thank you!

Comment: @Dom Day put your comment as answer so lowcoupling could mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add `a.read_more { display: none; }` to your css